# iPhone mvc question

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, delegates

In a standard iPhone application, how is the delegate to the UIApplication class identified to the UIApplication? Is it the fact that the delegate identifies itself as following the   protocol? Or is there some physical connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is made in MainWindow.nib. The `UIApplication` instance loads this NIB file and thereby creates the application delegate (which is an object in the NIB) and connects it to its delegate outlet.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is created in "Main nib file base base name" xib (NSMainNibFile), as defined in your Info.plist. The UIApplication defined in that xib has a UIApplicationDelegate IBOutlet that will define the delegate to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- as described by Ole and Felz
- in your main.m implementation file as drafted below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyCustomAppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal; 
}
```